# Update row in database using Google App Script

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script, jdbc, sql-update

I am trying to build the simple code to update a row in database using Google APP Script.

code executing without any errors but row in database is not getting updated. I am not sure where the code is going wrong.

```
var Database_Host = 'xxx.com'
var Database_Name = 'DB'
var Database_username = 'DB'
var Database_password = 'Password'
var Port_number = '306'             //DB details are hidden

function DB_Update(){

  var url = 'jdbc:mysql://' + Database_Host + ':' + Port_number + '/' + Database_Name
  Logger.log(url)
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(url, Database_username, Database_password);
  Logger.log(conn);

  conn.setAutoCommit(false);

    var stmt = conn.createStatement();
var results = stmt.executeUpdate('update time set flag = 0 where id in (13671)');
stmt.executeUpdate(results);
conn.commit();

  conn.setAutoCommit(true);
stmt.close();
conn.close();

}
```

Any help is appretiated.

Comment: This seems to be something specific to the database if you're not getting any exceptions. I tested your code and it works, but I had to remove the duplicate `stmt.executeUpdate(results);` line or I got a wrong syntax exception. After that correction the commits did go through so the script is mostly fine but there may be something else going on in your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

posting answer so that others can check and use.

Problem I am facing is I am connected to dev database and checking the prod database for updates, this issue is because both dev and prod share same user name and password.

DB details are least checked incase of errors, hence posting answer so that other can check if they forgot to check the connection details.